# Where to get libgrpc_csharp_ext.arm64.dylib?

Tags: grpc, google-ads-api, apple-m1, .net-6.0

When I try to run app with Google.Ads.GoogleAds nuget package on MacOS with M1 silicon I get the following error :

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Error loading
> native library. Not found in any of the possible locations: .../libgrpc_csharp_ext.arm64.dylib

Cannot really find where to obtain `libgrpc_csharp_ext.arm64.dylib` or where can I find source for it and how to compile.

Comment: Grpc C# (the Grpc.Core nuget package) doesn't currently support ARM64 on Mac, only on Linux.  In theory, you could build the grpc_csharp_ext native library from source, but I wouldn't recommend that unless you have a good understanding how gRPC works internally. You can try to switch the grpc library used to grpc-dotnet's Grpc.Net.Client (which does support M1 sillicon out of the box), but I'm not sure if the Google.Ads.GoogleAds supports that currently (there is ongoing work to make Grpc.Net.Client the default grpc implementation).

Answer (score 8):

You can try to use prebuilt version of the native .dylib for Apple M1 CPUs:

https://github.com/einari/Grpc.Core.M1

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Contrib.Grpc.Core.M1/

Comment: I just spent 2-3 hours trying to fix this problem. This solves it. Thank you. (I know typing meaningless comments is frowned upon, but, omg, awesome. I even tried using ChatGPT before this ,but that didnt help :P )

Comment: Can you please supply the detailed steps of adding the lib file to a project? I'm trying to build Azure Durable Functions and can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: There is a well detailed description here https://github.com/einari/Grpc.Core.M1

Comment: Interestingly enough installing the x64 version and not the Arm64 version solves this as well. No need for other packages.

Comment: @ChristopherPenkin can you explain how to do that?

Comment: @unlimitedfox, I used the [dotnet uninstall tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=macos) to remove all the SDKs and Runtimes from my machine.

Then go to [download dotnet](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) again and ensure to select the x64 installer and not the Arm64 one.

Answer (score 1):

You might have arrived here because you accidentally imported Grpc.Core instead of Grpc.Core.Api. If you are using grpc-dotnet (the now recommended package for grpc in dotnet applications), your code will compile when referencing the Grpc.Core package, but will fail trying to find `libgrpc_csharp_ext.arm64.dylib`. Switching from Grpc.Core to Grpc.Core.Api worked for me.

Comment: Grpc.Core.Api is implicit referenced by Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker, no explicit reference to gRpc. Fails on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was causing this, but now, referencing Google.Ads.GoogleAds 15.0.0 in project that uses .net 7 (I did update to latest runtime and sdk), no longer causes this issue. Previously, as a hot fix, I was running same code on linux VM instead.